# DB Design: Same Column used for 2 different foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm developing a method of joining 2 sources of Data (e.g. Queries).

I have a table Named QueryField with the following structure:

```
QueryID
FieldID
FieldName
```

....

If I have 2 records on QueryField

```
     QueryID         FieldID            FieldNAme
     ------------    ---------          ----------
     1               1                  CustomerID
     1               2                  CustAddress
     2               3                  CustNo
     2               4                  CustomerPhone
```

I want to have a new table QueryFieldJoin which defines which fields in the 2 queries to use to join on.  My idea was to have the following structure

```
 LeftJoinFieldID (FK from FieldID of QueryField)
 RightJoinFieldID (also FK from FieldID of QueryField)
 JoinType (intersect, outer join).
```

PrimaryKey is a combination of LeftJoinFieldID and RightJoinFieldID

```
    LeftJoinFieldID           RightJoinFieldId             JoinType
    --------------            ----------------             --------
    1                         3                            Intersect
```

This will work, however I feel that this isn't the best DB design having the same field as a foreign to two different columns on another table. Can anybody suggest a better approach?

Comment: Better approach: have two **separate** columns that each are the FK for one of the FK relationships. That way, you can also **enforce** the FK relationship in the database

Comment: +1 for the above comment

Comment: I'm not sure I get you, I already have 2 seperate columns in the QueryFieldJoin table?

Comment: The design looks fine to me. Seen it for an ORDERS table with SHIP_TO and BILL_TO fields both referencing back to an ADDRESS table.

Answer (score 0):

The DB Design also depends on what are your needs:

1) Which queries do you need to answer?
2) How fast do you need to access those data?

From an expressive POV, your design can be correct but maybe not the best solution depending on which queries you need to run.

For Instance, you might consider to have three different tables: One for the Fields, one for The Queries and one Operations.

Or even one big table with everything there if you do not want to perform any Join.